# Best approach to listen to a dynamic array of refs generated for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's the scenario: I get an initial payload from Firebase (eg. 5 objects) from `firebaseRef_1` (using a `.once` callback). I then transform each received object into a new Firebase ref. That newly generated ref looks like this:

```
 "data/ccccyyyyotKKiWC2xaV1WZ7H3/things/-KgXo121225H9_Nks1O"
```

If for example I have 5 incoming objects on that `.once` call, then I'll create 5 refs (see code snippet below).

Once I've created/generated the ref(s) I want to:

a) Create a .on listener to each of those 5 refs.

b) If (lets say) some time later 1 'row' of new data arrives to `firebaseRef_1`, I want to generate a new ref, and then create a listener - but now, **just for that newly added item**. Otherwise if I try to loop through all of the (now 6) elements Firebase throws a promise error telling me that the original 5  elements (refs) already have a listener attached.

The reason that I was thinking to use a `.once` call initially, is so that I can get the whole payload "all at `.once`" (pun intended!) which makes populating a `ListView` (react native) faster. I tried using a `.child_added` approach but on the *initial load* (of those 5 rows) the `.child_added` gets called 5 times and so you can see the rows appear one by one in the ListView which I dont like.

How should I best structure this in code to achieve what I've described above? Should I just have a `.once` call like this:

```
generateTheRefs() {
  firebase.database()
    .ref('data/' + firebaseUID + '/initialPath')
    .once('value', (snapshot) => {

     snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        let path = `data/${childData.item1}/things/${childData.item2}`;           

        //now create a .on listener
        firebase.database()
        .ref(path)
        .on('value', (snapshot) => {
             //....
        });
    });
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Read the entire initial set with once(), and display that. Store it in a variable somewhere.
2. Then immediately register a listener with on('child_added'), and only act on things you did not previously collect from once() as you initially stored it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are after is to use all of the results at the same time so they don't dribble in over time. You can use an array of promises and Promise.all() to wait for them all to arrive before using them, something like:

```
function generateTheRefs() {
  firebase.database()
      .ref('data/' + firebaseUID + '/initialPath')
      .once('value', (snapshot) => {

        let promises = [];

        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          let path = `data/${childData.item1}/things/${childData.item2}`;

          //now create a .on listener
          promises.push(firebase.database()
              .ref(path)
              .once('value'));
        });

        Promise.all(promises).then(snaps => {
          snaps.forEach(snap => {
            // ...
            console.log(snap.val());
          })              
        });
      });
}
```